# PromQL fractional query returning `null` when a scalar value is expected

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a boolean metric (i.e. samples are only ever either of the integers `0` or `1`) called `my_boolean_metric`. It has various labels, including a label `outcome` ranging over the values `{"success", "failure"}`. I am attempting a fractional query that should always return a floating point value between `0` and `1` inclusive.

The numerator query returns the number of `my_boolean_metric` time series matching the given labels, or `0` if there are no such time series.

`(count(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"}) or (1 - absent(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"nirvana", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"})))`

The value returned is an integer between `0` and `n` inclusive.

The denominator query returns the number of `my_boolean_metric` time series matching the given labels, unlike the numerator query it does not care about the "outcome" label.

`count(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar"})`

The value of this is always the integer `n`.

The following fractional query returns `null` (i.e. "No datapoints found" in the Prometheus/Thanos UI), even though each query as tested individually returns an integer.

`(count(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"}) or (1 - absent(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"}))) / count(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar"})`

The following fractional query with a hardcoded denominator does succeed.

`(count(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"}) or (1 - absent(my_boolean_metric{app="abc", team=~"foo", instance=~"bar", outcome="success"}))) / 9`

What is wrong with my fractional query?

Comment: I'm also looking for similar metric query, James did you got any fix for this Query to work?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not